# React-Native Navigator Tab not updating after rendering

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I wanted to start using navigator with my application, but seem to have ran into a problem.

I have a switch in a screen that is off by default. When pressed, it should call a function and turn to on. This works without a hitch when I call my function directly.

```
  toggleSwitch = (value) => {
      
      // TODO: Try to connect and send location
      if (value)
      {
        // some func
      }
      this.setState({switchValue: value})
  }

  home_render = () => {
    return(
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {/*onValueChange will be triggered after switch condition changes*/}
        
        <Switch
          trackColor={{false: 'gray', true: 'teal'}}
          thumbColor="white"
          
          onValueChange = {this.toggleSwitch}
          value = {this.state.switchValue}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
```

However when I call it with the navigator function the issue arises. The Switch wont turn on, upon pressing it once the value of the bool does seem to change to True (As I can see from the logs). But the switch remains off and wont let me change the value any longer. Below is my nav function. I am not sure if the issue is rendering? As the value should be updated.

```
 <NavigationContainer>{
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
          <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={this.login_render}/>
          <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={this.home_render}/> 
        </Stack.Navigator>
      }</NavigationContainer>
```

Any and all help would be appreciated, ive been thinking about it for couple days and cant figure it out. Thx should i just change to redux or smth?

Comment: I am fairly certain it might have to do with scope? But I am just not familiar enough to figure out where the issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And.. I messed up. It did appear to be a scope issue. In case anyone might find it useful I will attach what I did.

Changed the function declarations without the arrow notation

```
toggleSwitch(value){
```

and

```
home_render(){
```

Then when calling them I used the .bind

```
 component={this.home_render.bind(this)}/>
```